# if statement and permissions

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a script when the levels are admin,user and blogger

im using ifs so the can access the admin section using this:

```
if($general->logueado()){
if($general->SiEsAdmin()){
...code goes here....
}else{
    $general->redir('../index.php');
}
}else{
    $general->redir('../index.php');    
}
```

so `$general->logueado()` tells me if there is an active session and `$general->SiEsAdmin()` tell me if the user has the administrator level

if not they will be redirected to the index `($general->redir('../index.php');  )`

now my problem is that I need tho access the blogger level using like this:

```
if($general->logueado()){
    if($general->SiEsAdmin()){
    ...code goes here....
    }else{
        $general->redir('../index.php');
    }
if($general->tsBlogger()){
...code goes here....
    }else{
        $general->redir('../index.php');
    }
    }else{
        $general->redir('../index.php');    
    }
```

so the main problem is that neither admin or blogger cant access admin page how do i put code so admin can enter and blogger too but just few pages?

Comment: Can you rephrase or clarify the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your condition as

```
<?php
if ($general->logueado()) {
    if ($general->SiEsAdmin()) {
        //...code goes here....
    } else if ($general->tsBlogger()) {

      //...code goes here....
    } else {
        $general->redir('../index.php');
    }
} else {
    $general->redir('../index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($general->logueado()){
    if($general->SiEsAdmin()){
       //this is admin
        ...Admin code goes here....
    }else if($general->tsBlogger()){
        //this is blogger
        ... Blogger code goes here ...
    }else{
         // this is normal user
        $general->redir('../index.php');    
    }
}
```